# Trying to send Object from client to server in Socket.io ([Object object])

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm having a hard time trying to send a JS Object from the client socket to the server. I have a state on the React Component with the 'currentUser'. If I use this one, the emit won't work as expected.

```
state = {
 currentUser: { name: "hello" }
}

socket.emit('request_new_message', { timestamp: Date.now(), user: this.state.currentUser });
```

On the server, I got a simple console.log.

```
socket.on("request_new_message", (msg) => {
      console.log(msg)
   })
```

The expected output should be:

```
{timestamp: 12654676, user: { name: "hello" }}
```

But is printing:

```
{timestamp: 12654676, user: [Object object] }
```

Is this related to state? If so, how can I resolve the problem?
If not.. how can I resolve the problem?

Thank you,

Comment: did you tried `Object.assign()` or spread  operator.

Comment: For Object.assign don't know how to use it, and for spread-operator won't work with ...this.state.currentUser  (compile error)

Comment: Try to access the properties inside `user` to confirm that the `user` in sent as a string, `console.log(msg.user.name);`

Answer (score 0):

when you send data with socket or over http request always try to stringify it

```
state = {
 currentUser: { name: "hello" }
}

socket.emit('request_new_message', JSON.stringify({ timestamp: Date.now(), user: this.state.currentUser }));
```

then on server side you car parse it using

```
socket.on("request_new_message", (msg) => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(msg))
   })
```

hope this help :)

Comment: same problem 
`{ timestamp: ' ',
  text: 'dsfdsfdsf',
  user: '[object Object]' }`

Comment: so JSON.stringify({this.state.currentUser })

Comment: already tried the most common solutions, else won't be asking here. @Walid

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, create a temp object and use `Object.assign()`

```
state = {
 currentUser: { name: "hello" }
}
let obj = Object.assign({}, {timestamp:Date.now(), user: this.state.currentUser)
socket.emit('request_new_message', obj);
```

Comment: didn't work but thanks for the try - result: `{ timestamp: ' ', text: 'hello', user: '[object Object]' }`

Comment: please console obj and give result

Comment: That's what I just did upstairs:
`{ timestamp: ' ',
  text: 'Akhil Aravind',
  user: '[object Object]' }`